# Ways to compare two methods in general

Tags: performance, math

Background:
I have two methods to handle a set of problems. The key performance index is the dates to complete those set of problems. I want to assess which method is better base upon the overall dates is needed. For example, there are two methods called, A and B. There are a set of problems containing 3 problems, which are x, y, and z. Using method A to approach these three problems needs 3, 5, 7 days respectively. Whereas using method B needs 6, 7, 8 days respectively. I need to compare whether A is better or B is better. In this naive example, A is obviously better.

However, there is an edge case. It could happen that for some problems, one method would takes forever to finish it. For example, there is another method called C. To approach x, y, and z, it needs 1, 1, and 99999 days to finish. My question is how I can compare C to A and B?

There are two ways I am considering. One is reciprocal of dates. The other one is truncated. On the previous example, if I use reciprocal, then the scores of method A are (1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7)/3, method B are (1/6 + 1/7 + 1/8)/3, and method C are (1/1 + 1/1 + 1/99999)/3. Based upon reciprocal, A > C > B. If I use truncated to 30 (any value bigger than 30 become 30). Then the average needed dates for method A is 5, method B is 7, and method C is 10.7.

My question are

1. which criterion is better?
2. Is there any other ways to assess?
3. If truncation is better, is there a better way to set the cutoff point?
4. If reciprocal is better, how to interpret that number? average efficiency? and how to report to boss what that number means.
5. Is there any more structure, or scientific way to think of this kind of problem in general?

Any helps or hints is appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: *The key performance index is the dates to complete those set of problems.* Don't you just mean you want to choose the method which finishes all the tasks soonest?  I don't understand why you are doing any arithmetic other than addition.

Comment: The problem is that if there is a method fails only one job (It never gets that task done), but it does a really good job for others, say 1 day. Another method takes 30 day for every job. If I just simply sum up all the dates each method consumes, then the performance of first method is underestimated. That is the reason why I am considering any complicated arithmetic

Comment: *If I just simply sum up all the dates each method consumes, then the performance of first method is underestimated.* If a method fails on a job its completion time is infinite. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify my question a little bit. Actually, it is acceptable for a method that fails on "some" jobs. In my scenario, the method that fails only one job, but it makes a significant improvement to all other jobs is better than the other one. However, I don't know how to balance failure and efficiency. Hope I make my question more clear